# i want to randomly change the gradient angle from javascript

Tags: javascript, css

This is what i've tried till now.

```
function Setcol(){

     var rangrad = Math.floor((Math.random() * 360) + 1);

     var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("body");

    elem.style.background="linear-gradient(" + rangrad + ", #FF0000 2%, #FFBFBF 100%)"; }
```

Comment: [`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of elements

Answer (score 2):

Link say Andreas, you get a collection of elements, so your fixed code is :

```
function Setcol() {
    var rangrad = Math.floor((Math.random() * 360) + 1);
    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    elem.style.background="linear-gradient(" + rangrad + ", #FF0000 2%, #FFBFBF 100%)"; 
}
```

Or add an id attribut to your body tag and use something like this

```
function Setcol() {
    var rangrad = Math.floor((Math.random() * 360) + 1);
    var elem = document.getElementsById("idOfBody");
    elem.style.background="linear-gradient(" + rangrad + ", #FF0000 2%, #FFBFBF 100%)"; 
}
```

Both will work.

Comment: what if i changed the .getElemetByTagName to ByID

Comment: You can also do that, but don't forget to add a id attribut to your body tag.

Comment: And my bad, the first solution doesn't work (with the ".shift()"), sorry for my mistake ...

Comment: Thanks you so much Your the best :)

Comment: Just use [`document.body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body)...